# Why componentDidMount in higher order component called more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) says:

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs.

Now, when I try to create a higher order component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function wrap(Wrapped) {

  class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      // I will place some reusable functionality here which need to
      // be called once on mounted.
      console.log('wrapper component mounted');
    }
    render() {
      return <Wrapped {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
  return Wrapper;
}

class Wrapped extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('wrapped component mounted');
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

connect()(wrap(Wrapped));
```

Now, every time any changes occur in props, the console will print this:

```
'wrapped component mounted'
'wrapper component mounted'
```

If I remove the `Wrapper`, it will only print this once (when mounted
in the first time):

```
`wrapped component mounted`
```

So, Why componentDidMount in higher order component called more than once?

Comment: connect()(wrap(Wrapper));  <-- replace with Wrapped

Comment: @ffxsam I'm sorry If I don't understand your comment correctly, my English is not that good. But, If I'm not wrong, when those component (`Wrapper` and `Wrapped`) is already mounted, `componentDidMount` will not be called again as long as it is not unmounted. And what I mean here is those two `componentDidMount` is always called, whenever props changes.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I missed the part about the props changes causing `componentDidMount` to fire again. Very strange.

Comment: @Utro I'm planning to add some reusable functionality in `componentDidMount` on `Wrapper` component. The above code is before that functionality is written, of course I can move that functionality to `Wrapped` component. In this case I need that `componentDidMount` on `Wrapper` component.

Comment: See Utro's answer below, he's right. You mistakenly have `connect()(wrap(Wrapper));` but it should be `connect()(wrap(Wrapped));`

Comment: @ffxsam sorry, typo. I mean the problem occurs when `Wrapped` there too. Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**connect()(wrap(Wrapper)); <-- replace with Wrapped**

I have tested it. And it works.

```
function wrap(Wrapped) {
  class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('wrapper component mounted');
    }
    render() {
      return <Wrapped {...this.props}/>
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        console.log(this.props);
    }
  }
  return Wrapper;
}
class Wrapped extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('wrapped component mounted');
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      console.log(this.props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

connect(state=>({state}))(wrap(Wrapped));
```

**wrap func returns Wrapper, you can't pass the Wrapper into wrap func. it's loop**

Comment: Sorry, i miss typing when typing the question. I updated the question

Comment: but it invokes only once componentDidMount

Comment: Are you sure? How did you test that? It is invoked every time in my case.

Comment: i pass down state through connect, and then i change state , in order to recieve new props in wrpapped components

Comment: I see. What I'm doing is changing the props directly in the code via `react-hot-loader`. Because without higher order component, `componentDidMount` is not invoked when I edit the props, and `hot-loader` updates. So, there's no problem then.